# Replicate row value following a factor

Tags: r, data.table

Given the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(patientID = rep(c(1:4), 3), 
                 condition = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B",4), rep("C",4)),
                 weight = round(rnorm(12, 70, 7), 1),
                 height = round(c(rnorm(4, 170, 10), rep(0, 8)), 1))

> head(df)
  patientID condition weight height
1         1         A  71.43  168.5
2         2         A  59.89  177.3
3         3         A  72.15  163.4
4         4         A  70.14  166.1
5         1         B  66.21    0.0
6         2         B  66.62    0.0
```

How can I copy the height for each patient from condition A into the other two conditions? I tried using for loops, data.table and dplyr without success.

How can I achieve this using either methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is as it looks - sorted by `condition, patientID`, and the patients per condition are identical, then you can just make use of *recycling* as follows:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)[, height := height[condition == "A"]]
```

But I understand that's a lot of *ifs* there.

---

So, without assuming anything about the data, with one exception that `condition,patientID` pairs are unique, you can do:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)[, height := height[condition == "A"], by=patientID]
```

Once again, this makes use of *recycling*, but within each group - as it doesn't assume the data is ordered.

---

Both of the above methods on the sample data give:

```
#     patientID condition weight height
# 1:          1         A   73.3  169.5
# 2:          2         A   76.3  173.4
# 3:          3         A   63.6  145.5
# 4:          4         A   56.2  164.7
# 5:          1         B   67.7  169.5
# 6:          2         B   77.3  173.4
# 7:          3         B   76.8  145.5
# 8:          4         B   70.9  164.7
# 9:          1         C   76.6  169.5
# 10:         2         C   73.0  173.4
# 11:         3         C   66.7  145.5
# 12:         4         C   71.6  164.7
```

The same idea can be translated to `dplyr` as well, which I'll leave it to you to try. Hint: it just requires `group_by` and `mutate`.

Answer (score 1):

No need for the fancy stuff here.  Just use the `$` operator and `[` subsetting.

```
> df$height <- df$height[df$patientID]
> df
   patientID condition weight height
1          1         A   67.4  175.1
2          2         A   66.8  179.0
3          3         A   49.7  159.7
4          4         A   64.5  165.3
5          1         B   66.0  175.1
6          2         B   70.8  179.0
7          3         B   58.7  159.7
8          4         B   74.3  165.3
9          1         C   70.9  175.1
10         2         C   75.6  179.0
11         3         C   61.3  159.7
12         4         C   74.5  165.3
```

Comment: This isn't robust to permutations of the rows, right? `df<-df[sample(nrow(df)),]; df$height <- df$height[df$patientID]` So you're assuming everything must be sorted?

Comment: I agree. The sample data is sorted. I just wanted to make it clear that is a requirement. Also this only would work for patientIDs that start at 1. If you added 10 to every ID you would have a problem as well, unless you convert patient ID to a factor.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. It assumes that the first level of the condition factor is always the one with the true data.

```
idx <- tapply(rownames(df), list(df$patientID, df$condition), identity)
idx<-na.omit(cbind(as.vector(idx[,-1]),as.vector(idx[,1])))
df[as.vector(idx[,1]),"height"] <- df[as.vector(idx[,2]), "height"]
```

And from @Arun's suggestion

```
df$height<-with(df, ave(ifelse(condition=="A",height,-1), 
    factor(patientID), FUN=max))
```

where you can be explicit about the condition level to pull values from

Comment: Good point @Arun. The double column issue was plaguing me. I ended up using `ifelse` as above. Did you have another idea in mind for using `ave`?

Comment: @Arun I see. That's very nice too.

Comment: @arun Yes. If all the missing values are 0 (or at least less than A). It would work fine. I just want to make sure to overwrite anything in the conditions other than A just in case some random other data as in there.